# Effects of partitionBy(HashPartitioner) on a cached RDD when few values are modified

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to know what happen when I put in cache a RDD then get a new RDD by modifying a limited number of values.

```
  rdd.cache
  val rdd2 = rdd.map(x=>if(cond) partitionValue else x)
```

The part of RDD which hasn't been touch is it still in cache if I used rdd2 ?

Moreover I need to update the partition in which are the modified values so I

```
  val rdd2bis = rdd2.partitionBy(HashPartioner(nbPart))
```

And I would like to iterate this process for each datapoint :

- Find in which partition should go one value.
- Modify my value and put it in the right partition using `partitionBy`.

So my main question is if `partitionBy` keeps output RDD in memory if only few members have been modified?

I know that the partitionBy gives a new RDD as output but is there any chance that some of the non modified cached values are still in cache for the generated RDD.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know what happen when i put in cache a RDD then get a new RDD by modifying limited number of value.

If you literally modify mutable objects in place you'll end up with programming which is incorrect and nondeterministic.

> The part of rdd which hasn't been touch is it still in cache if i used rdd2 ?

If you `map` without modifying existing objects it won't affect cached data at all. `rdd` should be cached as it was (unless evicted due to memory issues), `rdd2` won't be. Nevertheless data is not copied so "unchanged" records in `rdd2` reference the same objects as `rdd`.

> if partitionBy keeps output RDD in memory if only few members have been modified

No. `partitionBy` requires standard shuffle mechanism. Once again it doesn't really affected cached state of the `rdd`.